# How to draw a curve path after straight lines in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

What I need is to draw a curve like the one shown on the right side of the picture below.

```
    struct DrawingPaths: View {
        var body: some View {
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 430, y: 0))
                path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:430, y: 0), control: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 5))
            }
            .fill(.blue)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a quad curve with 2 control points.

```
struct DrawingPaths: View {
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            //Top left
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            //Left vertical bound
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300))
            //Curve
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 430, y: 200), control1: CGPoint(x: 175, y: 350), control2: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 80))
            //Right vertical bound
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 450, y: 0))
        }
        .fill(.blue)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, I need to practice more, paths seem very cool in SwiftUI, at least seem easier than in UIKit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fs_tigre yeah I try drawing the images on a piece of paper without lifting the pencil . It is easier for me to visualize each `path.add...`. Also, I like using `Shape` so the paths can be relative to the available rect for multiple screens.

Comment: @ lorem ipsum  Wow, that's a great idea, drawing the shapes on paper gives you a good idea of where the points and controls need to be, something so simple but I didn't think about it. Either way, I didn't notice that I needed the two control points for that type of curve, it's very simple. Would you mind elaborating more on your comment about multiple screens? Or you meant to say shapes? Thanks a LOT.

Comment: @fs_tigre No, `Shape` that way you can use the `rect` from `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path` then you can use percentages such as substitute `300` in the first `addLine` with `rect.maxY * 0.35` just make a `struct` conform to `Shape` `struct CurvedTop: Shape`

Comment: Ah, screen sizes, got it. I agree, making a struct and returning `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path`  makes it easier to place the shape on the screen and feels more `SwiftUI` native. Thanks a lot for your help